Can anyone sum up a solution that really work to upload a zip file in SSH to Gdrive using Python?
My current approach is using this code:

from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

upload_file_list = ['checkpoint-5824.zip']

exist_file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'{}' in parents and trashed=false".format("1PtwHBXcXdmamofSgZZNpgw7wo...")}).GetList()

for upload_file in upload_file_list:
    if (not os.path.exists(upload_file)):
        continue

    fileName = os.path.basename(upload_file)
    for file1 in exist_file_list:
        if file1['title'] == fileName:
            file1.Delete()

    gfile = drive.CreateFile({'parents': [{'id': "1PtwHBXcXdmamofSgZZNpgw7..."}], 'title': fileName})
    # Read file and set it as the content of this instance.
    gfile.SetContentFile(upload_file)
    gfile.Upload()  # Upload the file.



combine with a settings.yaml

client_config_backend: settings
client_config:
  client_id:
  client_secret: 

save_credentials: True
save_credentials_backend: file
save_credentials_file: credentials.json

get_refresh_token: True

oauth_scope:
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install


But I fail at identification step on browser due to cannot connect via local host.
Anyone knows a solution?

I am assuming the Authentication API uses a callback function that targets your API via a HTTP request to inform it of the status of the authentication (successful or failed). For this purpose, you can use ngrok which gives you a random URL which basically tells your API what request is coming on that API, forwarding it to your local network.

Thank you for your answering. But can you give me a hint to do that, like I don't know anything about ngrok T.T  @Dimitar

You can follow the documentation provided in this GitHub repo: https://github.com/ngrok/ngrok-python. Also, a simple ChatGPT prompt would suffice, it is relatively simple to set up, and the documentation is comprehensive,
